# How to make custom resource definition to read value from kubernetes secrets

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am developing kubernetes operator based on ansible.
I am trying to read the tls.key and tls.crt from kubernetes secrets issued by let's encrypt and with ansible tasks convert it to windows IIS cert.

```
apiVersion: win-cert.test.net/v1alpha1
kind: WindowsCert
metadata:
  name: windowscert-sample
spec:
  pfx_file: test
  pfx_state: present
  pfx_crt: 
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: cert-manager
        key: tls.crt
  pfx_key:
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: cert-manager
        key: tls.key

  pfx_ca: ''
  
  pfx_output_file: ''
```

My custom resource definition look like this:

```
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: windowscerts.win-cert.tests.net
spec:
  group: win-cert.test.net
  names:
    kind: WindowsCert
    listKind: WindowsCertList
    plural: windowscerts
    singular: windowscert
  scope: Namespaced
  versions:
  - name: v1alpha1
    schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        description: WindowsCert is the Schema for the windowscerts API
        properties:
          apiVersion:
            description: 'APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation
              of an object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest
              internal value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources'
            type: string
          kind:
            description: 'Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this
              object represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client
              submits requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds'
            type: string
          metadata:
            type: object
          spec:
            description: Spec defines the desired state of WindowsCert
            type: object
            x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true
            properties:
              cronSpec:
                description: 'Specify under crontab format interval to run windows cert ansible playbook'
                type: string
                pattern: '^(\d+|\*)(/\d+)?(\s+(\d+|\*)(/\d+)?){4}$'
                default: "5 0 * * *"
              pfx_file:
                type: string
              pfx_state: 
                type: string
              pfx_crt:
                type: string
              pfx_ca: 
                type: string
              pfx_key:
                type: string
              pfx_output_file:
                type: string
          status:
            description: Status defines the observed state of WindowsCert
            type: object
            x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true
        type: object
    served: true
    storage: true
    subresources:
      status: {}
```

How can I populate this field pfx_key and cert field with values from secret?

Comment: What code do you have so far for your controller?  Are you using a framework like kubebuilder or operator-sdk?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using operator-sdk

Comment: Please try adding some more info about what you've tried and what problems you're seeing.

I'd also recommend trying to solve this problem using standard ansible, rather than using the operator framework. This question indicates a lack of understanding of kubernetes overall - adding in operators will only make things more complex from here.

Comment: any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ansible provides the [k8s_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_info_module.html) module for retrieving objects.

You should be able to use a block like this

```
- name: Get the secret passed into our CRD
  community.kubernetes.k8s_info:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Secret
    name: foobar
    namespace: bizbang
  register: my_secret
```

However... I'd really recommend not using the operator framework for this task. Kubernetes and the operator framework will add more problems and complexity than required.

Check out the [letsencrypt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/letsencrypt_module.html) module.

Comment: thanks for the info, I tried. 
I need an operator because i have to automate other things in different clusters and environments.

Is this part okay? Can I use secretKeyRef in this way?

pfx_crt: 
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: cert-manager
        key: tls.crt
  pfx_key:
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: cert-manager
        key: tls.key